# Regular Expression for Password strength with one special characters except Underscore

Tags: regex, model-view-controller

I have the following regular expression:

```
^.*(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*-])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

I am using it to validate for 
         **At least one letter

        least one capital letter

        least one number

        least one special characters

        least 8 characters**

But along with this I need to restrict the underscore (`_`). 
If I enter password `Pa$sw0rd`, this is validating correctly, which is true.
If I enter `Pa$_sw0rd` this is also validating correctly, which is wrong.

The thing is the regex is passing when all the rules are satisfied. I want a rule to restrict underscore along with above.

Any help will be very appreciable.

Comment: there should be no `_` ??????

Comment: Having one regular expression for each of the requirements would make the whole thing easier to code, understand, update and to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a negated character class `[^_]*` to add this restriction (also, remove the initial `.*`, it is redundant, and the first look-ahead is already at the beginning of the pattern, no need to duplicate `^`, and it is totally redundant since the total length limit can be checked at the end):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*-])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])[^_]{8,}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fR5yP9/2)

Comment: You are very welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked for you (a tick on the left below the down arrow).

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[!@#$%^&*-])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?!.*_).{8,}$
```

You can try this.`.*` at start is of no use.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/34

Comment: You are adding another look-ahead with `.*`, this decreases performance.

Comment: @stribizhev yups but i feel adding an answer which shows another way or a new method to deal d same thing though not same performance wise if ok :) adds to the knowledge kitty :)